# Appending another key generated in PuTTYgen to authorized_keys file

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty, public-key, authorized-keys

I allowed Amazon to create a key pair for me. It works, I can ssh in.

I used PuTTYgen to create another key pair.

Followed directions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys and http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-multiple-ssh-key-based-authentication.html

- I executed command `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- restarted the ssh service

Resulting `authorized_keys` looks like this :

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCIm2L1LrZji0ZjS0BFpo+lPresjSzBru2kZYQFwT2fB/6vsC+n1hPmA5peRkubMk5ahGawvqODX4ERYYMkP/imKK95el3Gx9n1zUO58PR2EH7qeRHZYtw1OwivDndTgB3eykJGtwJ80iyKa/H0yI8QdKNeQk91fRe9SntCHO63xfqvZKUjNgDtXhGmRAumCcwdMHU4viWlgIGcj7mARz+JDTD/8s8JbiW7UyUqxKGDwv0TZxxNbvIbUduQ61hkogPPaK9ECRBX5cc0iS44FgG8SbIGUZLt7/eV5tc8pAjQc5pWyZBDewV4E2HbCtHM6MoWtbmMKQjIzSauUnkUCWG/ crave
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20141212"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEA03FN7q5+yoRw3Fp9iJbd70Mc1Cbrc+z8SsFT
DaP27uoJy9eRjizikkIEhJNAU9Ql86S78oJzfiw+DrWVeoMHBMmY6yV/KFHBYlhl
waJp7dk9hwlQyCZRY4iiZT2o+TPcYj0FCk1V/Am8svtlgVNuRfo9G4zmBeRc+Njt
zfTZDmUpN1u70FVNOhGNHq2rSyG+Q8RJO1pX8jg82kXusHxZRMK6LlhBdaWEbr2w
Y8X89Eqg2UjNfkl4cOmx3rvVfK6xHbKoeGPEdDXDKghiflM1GCNwG4khIBDBLXZs
8bYzeTcIKGa3WAN7MoO1tvVKwpMVHR673Ypz3dLpD53WjxNmCw==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

The first one still works with the private key generated by Amazon but the second public key doesn't recognize the private key PuTTYgen created.

I get

> Server refused our key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I follow the (correct) instructions you have pointed to yourself, my `id_rsa.pub` file follows expected format:

```
ssh-rsa <key> comment>
```

Had you appended a public key in the above format, it would work.

While I believe you actually have not followed the instructions, but saved the public key from PuTTYgen is its own multi-line format (as we can see in your resulting `authorized_keys`).

OpenSSH server does not understand that format.

Solutions:

- Either really follow the instructions you have pointed to completely (particularly generate the key pair using `ssh-keygen`)
- Or follow PuTTYgen instructions and copy-paste the public key in OpenSSH format from PuTTYgen box labeled *Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file*.

Comment: You're spot on. I followed the directions loosely. It's hard to find an example of authorized_keys with several public keys so now that I got it working. Let me paste how it should look.
`ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCIm2L1LrZji0ZjS0BFpo+lPresjSzBru2kZYQFwT2fB/6vsC+n1hPmA5peRkubMk5ahGawvqODX4ERYYMkP/UnkUCWG/ crave
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAgHXRRtv6wk90tx6Uo8Blg1xTjvN6tzd0QtZCLPU+oqOrkFMQ== rsa-key-20141212`